# sql server filestream equivalent in oracle database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, filestream

I want to transfer data from an SQL Server 2008 R2 database to a Oracle 11g Database, A very straightforward ETL operation. But in the SQL Server a Database is using the Filestream functionality to store certain videos and images, but the Oracle database does not have this functionality to my knowledge.
Is there anyone out there who has come across this kind of situation earlier? What was the solution you applied? Simply stored the binary files in a separate server or simply used the BLOB type to store the files?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [`BFILE` type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_bfile_ops.htm).  This is an Oracle data type that allows you to work with binary data that is stored on the file system outside the database.

Comment: However I just noted that you can only read these files but cannot make any changes to it. Since the files are in the disk the database does not have any control over them. It was very good for the reading operations in the applications. But if you want to make changes to these files I found out that using the ORDSYS.ORDImage type in Oracle database and use the Class OrdImage (If you are using Java, of course) in your application.